# Admob Interstitial Cocos2d Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, admob

i'm searching on google but i only find the way to integrate the AdMob Banner View on my app in Cocos2d. Now I need to put the full screen AdMob interstitial and i don't find the way to do it :. Please Help me, how i can do it??

I'm not sure what source code i need to post... I would like to show the interstitial when the app startup and when there is the game over.

I already tried [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial)

but it gave me some error.

Comment: cocos2d 3.x or cocos2d 2.x ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AppDelegate.h, add GADInterstitialDelegate

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate>
{
}
-(void)showAdmobFullScreenAds;
@end

#define App ((AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)showAdmobFullScreenAds
{
    GADInterstitial  *interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-YOUR_ID";
    interstitial_.delegate = self;
    [interstitial_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

}

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial
{
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector]];
}
```

// In GameOver class, add #import "AppDelegate.h" then use below function

```
   [App showAdmobFullScreenAds];
```

Comment: My app delegate.h now have this : @interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate> it's this a problem?

Comment: ok i did it and now on app delegate.m it say an error on void showadmofullscreenads : use of undeclared identifier 'shoAdmobFullScreenAds' I need to put at least?

Comment: for which variable its showing  undeclared identifier  ?

Comment: For the -(void)showAdmobFullScreenAds, but i resolve that by put on the final line....But now it say another error : property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'appController*' in the line [mInterstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self.navigationController]; Thank's for your fast reply :)

Comment: which version of cocos2d you are using ?

Comment: replace [CCDirector sharedDirector]  in place of self.navigationController.

Comment: i'm using cocos2d 2.x

Comment: It works, thank you very very much! But now if i want to show that on the game over i put  [self showAdmobFullScreenAds];
 in the gameoverscene.m ??

Comment: No, in gameover, just call function in App Delegate...updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, but how i can do it?

Comment: Updated my answer...follow same.

Comment: "Use of undeclared identity App" are you sure is not [Self showAdmobFullScreenAds];  ??

Comment: hmm...see my answer again...I added code  #define App after end of class  AppController. check above answer again....

Comment: Yes it works! Really thank you, you save my life ahah